# mysql_safe requires user to press enter

Tags: mysql, unix

User needs to press enter after the below  "mysql_safe" command is executed. It displays the below line on screen and waits for user to press enter key -

```
$     /opt/mysql-5.7.19-linux-glibc2.12-x86_64/bin/mysqld_safe  --defaults-file=/etc/my_5719.cnf  &
    [1] 26310
    $ 2017-10-30T04:07:06.950000Z mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/mysqld5719.log'.
    2017-10-30T04:07:06.970013Z mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /opt/mysql5719/data
```

I searched the web and could not find much help on same, tried all the below options seperately -

```
echo "\n" |<< above command>> 
echo "y" |<< above command>>
yes "" |<< above command>>
<< above command>> <<EOD

EOD
```

and similar options, but nothing worked for me. 
I tried checking mysqld and mysqld_safe options and tried silent and few other options as well. My requirement is to use this command without any user interaction. Can someone please help me in avoiding manual intervention for this command.

Comment: try `yes | your-comand` that will send "yes" as many times it is required

Comment: Is it waiting for you to press a key? Your prompt is here >>> `$ 2017-10-30T04:07:...`